# Merge and delete rows in Excel if cells in a specific column are the same

Tags: vba, excel

I searched for something along these lines, but couldn't find any answers that did exactly what I was looking for. What I have is a spreadsheet of apparel items that are split up by size. For example:

```
Product Name  |  Image      |  Color  |  Size  
_______________________________________________
tshirt        |  tshirt.jpg |  White  |  Small
tshirt        |  tshirt.jpg |  White  |  Medium
tshirt        |  tshirt.jpg |  White  |  Large
polo          |  polo.jpg   |  Blue   |  Small
polo          |  polo.jpg   |  Blue   |  Medium
polo          |  polo.jpg   |  Blue   |  Large
...
```

What I would like to have happen is for the all of the sizes for the same item be condensed to one line like so:

```
Product Name  |  Image      |  Color  |  Size  
_______________________________________________
tshirt        |  tshirt.jpg |  White  |  Small Medium Large
polo          |  polo.jpg   |  Blue   |  Small Medium Large
...
```

I found this script but it only deletes the rows and doesn't merge the sizes into one cell:

```
Sub removeDups()

Dim myRow As Long
Dim sTRef As String

sTRef = Cells(2, 2)

myRow = 1
Do While (Cells(myRow, 2) <> "")

If (sTRef <> Cells(myRow, 2)) Then
sTRef = Cells(myRow, 2)
myRow = myRow + 1

Else

Rows(myRow).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End If
Loop
End Sub
```

How can I modify this script to merge the sizes before deleting the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code (I suppose that your sizes in column "E"):

```
Sub removeDups()

    Dim myRow As Long
    Dim sTRef As String

    sTRef = Cells(2, 2)

    myRow = 3
    Do While Cells(myRow, 2) <> ""

        If sTRef <> Cells(myRow, 2) Then
            sTRef = Cells(myRow, 2)
            myRow = myRow + 1
        Else
            Cells(myRow - 1, "E") = Cells(myRow - 1, "E") & " " & Cells(myRow, "E")
            Rows(myRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

simoco's answer can be made more general as follows:

Dataset:

```
╔══════════════╦════════════╦═══════╦════════╦════════════════╗
║ Product Name ║   Image    ║ Color ║  Size  ║     E-mail     ║
╠══════════════╬════════════╬═══════╬════════╬════════════════╣
║ tshirt       ║ tshirt.jpg ║ White ║ Small  ║ john@gmail.com ║
║ tshirt       ║ tshirt.jpg ║ White ║ Medium ║ bob@gmail.com  ║
║ tshirt       ║ tshirt.jpg ║ White ║ Large  ║ bob@gmail.com  ║
║ polo         ║ polo.jpg   ║ Blue  ║ Small  ║ bob@gmail.com  ║
║ yolo         ║            ║ Blue  ║ Medium ║ jack@gmail.com ║
║ holo         ║            ║ Blue  ║ Large  ║ jack@gmail.com ║
║ rolo         ║ polo.jpg   ║       ║ Small  ║ jack@gmail.com ║
║ yolo         ║ polo.jpg   ║ Blue  ║ Medium ║ joe@gmail.com  ║
║ holo         ║            ║ Blue  ║ Large  ║ joe@gmail.com  ║
║ rolo         ║            ║       ║ Small  ║ joe@gmail.com  ║
╚══════════════╩════════════╩═══════╩════════╩════════════════╝
```

Assumptions:

- Let column E contain the value you want merged into one.
- Let 5 be the amount of columns that exist in the worksheet.
- Let us merge all cells in all other columns that are not equal.
- Let us introduce a % sign, so that we can use conditional formatting to find all the cells where data has been merged.
- Let us take into account empty cells.

The resulting code is:

```
Sub removeDups()
    Dim myRow As Long
    Dim sTRef As String
    sTRef = Cells(2, "E")
    myRow = 3
    Do While Cells(myRow, "E") <> ""
        If sTRef <> Cells(myRow, "E") Then
            sTRef = Cells(myRow, "E")
            myRow = myRow + 1
        Else
            For i = 1 To 5
                If Cells(myRow - 1, i) = "" Then
                    Cells(myRow - 1, i) = Cells(myRow, i)
                Else
                        If Cells(myRow, i) = Cells(myRow - 1, i) Then
                            Cells(myRow - 1, i) = Cells(myRow, i)
                        Else
                            If Cells(myRow, i) <> "" Then
                                Cells(myRow - 1, i) = Cells(myRow - 1, i) & " % " & Cells(myRow, i)
                            End If
                        End If
                End If
            Next i
            Rows(myRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

simoco, thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

My solution assumes every colum has to be the same except for the colum with values you want to merge.

Put the code in the VBA module linked to the worksheet you are working on. As in your example it assumes the table to be sorted.

```
Const MergeCol = 4

Sub MergeRows()
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim Col As Long
    Dim Equal As Boolean

    With Me.UsedRange
        For Row = 3 To .Rows.Count
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(Row, 1)) Then
                Equal = True
                For Col = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    If Col <> MergeCol Then
                        If .Cells(Row - 1, Col).Value <> .Cells(Row, Col).Value Then
                            Equal = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next Col
                If Equal Then
                    ' Merge
                    With .Cells(Row - 1, MergeCol)
                        .Value = .Value & ", " & Me.Cells(Row, MergeCol).Value
                    End With
                    .Rows(Row).Delete
                    Row = Row - 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```